# Crashlytics crash rate much higher than user count in crash issues

Tags: android, crashlytics

The new release of my app shows a crash-free rate of 96.92% (filtered to that single version code.) If I hover to get the details of the crash rate, it says there were 3952 crashed users in the past seven days. If I total up the number of users for all the issues in the list, it comes to 85 users and 116 events. I understand that there may be some discrepancy because the crash-free rate comes from Google Analytics, but I can't make any sense of this vast difference. How can I fix the crashes if I don't know what they are?

I've read the other questions with answers about it's total users and not unique users, but none of those appear to explain how 116 crash events could produce 3952 users experiencing crashes. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the answer. I'm pretty sure the analytics values that produce the crash-free rate are not filtered based on the selected versionCode values, only by the version name. In my case, since my app was in a staged rollout, I was updating the versionCode with each fix, but not the version name. If I change that filter, the crash-free rate doesn't change.

Since the reason for the fix I'm trying to track is that one with an earlier versionCode had a (relatively) high crash rate. So the small number of issues in the list tells me those crashes really are fixed, but I won't see the crash-free rate improve until more users update and the earlier-version crashes are no longer in the time frame. (In the future, I'll increment the version name which I think will avoid this problem.)